# Vuejs multiple vue instances, throws undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Update:
I tried removing the nesting and it works fine. It definitely should be the nesting. But would love any-sort of feedback to make it work.

I have an application using multiple instances of vuejs. When I am trying to load a particular property of an instance, it throws undefined error. I spent last couple of hours researching but could not find the cause behind it. Looking forward for some suggestions.

**Error:**

> Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

**Main.js**

```
// Vue.js is already loaded
// there are some other instances of vuejs with unique names as `freeRegVueApp`.

    const freeRegVueApp = document.getElementById("freeRegVueApp") ? new Vue({
        el: '#freeRegVueApp',
        /**
         * some things we might want to pass around between components of the vueApp VUE instance
         */
        data:
            {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            },
        mounted:function(){
            this.method1(); //method1 will execute at pageload
        },
        methods:{
            method1:function(){
                alert('loaded');
            }
        },
    }) : null;
```

**Signup.blade.php**

```
<!-- Some instances of vuejs -->
<div id="someVueInstance">

    <div class="signupForm" id="freeRegVueApp">
       <p v-if="message"> @{{message}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could this be because I am nesting vuejs instances?

Comment: It appears `message` gets evaluated in the context of a Vue instance that doesn't have a `message` method or data, probably before you instantiate the nested Vue instance which, from what you're presenting, has it defined in data. If you need more help, try to provide a [mcve] where one would be able to experience the bug as well as try out various potential fixes.

Comment: Try to return an object which contains the properties instead: `data: function() { return { message: 'hello'} }`